# rotate text IE Microsoft.Matrix

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

First time I am using this, to rotate a text in IE
on other browsers like safari,chromo,firefox,opera the rotated text looks fine and mouseover on text looks ok.

Only for IE, the rotated text looks pixelate.... its blurry and when mouseover (change color) it looks hideous as out of focus...

Can anyone help me how to fix this and make things all sharp and goodlooking again?

Does it have something to do with the auto expand (sizingmethod?) are there other methods?

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're up against a browser limitation.  In general, I think IE actually does a better job rendering fonts...at default sizes they look really good.  But when you start messing with sizing, offset, etc....especially with older versions of IE.....it's not going to look great.

What are your solutions?  For some elements you might be able to [Langridge-Leahy](http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/) but that's not at all practical many things.  Trying different fonts might give you a slight improvement, but likely won't ever be the perfect answer.  You could work with the designer to cut back on angled elements for only essential elements.  Many developers I know just throw up their hands and deal because it's Microsoft.  It certainly ain't fun...

You --could-- always have some fun with your users like this:  http://ie6update.com/